# Creating folders based on part of a filename

Tags: bash, macos, directory

I have a bunch of audiobooks in one folder on macOS. The file naming structure is `Author - Title.m4b` (e.g. `JRR Tolkien - Lord of the Rings.m4b`). I would like to run a bash script and then have the following folder structure:

- Author (folder)
- --> Title (folder)
- ----> Audiobook m4b file (naming as above, unchanged)

So the file would be in the book folder in the author folder.

I have found this script:

```
find . -type f -name "*jpg" -maxdepth 1 -exec bash -c 'mkdir -p "${0%%_*}"' {} \; \
-exec bash -c 'mv "$0" "${0%%_*}"' {} \;
```

But it "only" takes the author as a folder and puts the file in there. I have not found a way to take the title and make this another subfolder level.

Comment: So the output you want is `Author/Title/Title.m4b` correct?

Comment: `find . -type f -name "*jpg" ` means your looking for files ending in `.jpg` while your sample file name ends in `.m4b` what gives?

Comment: Sorry, I did not change the original script, but you are correct: Author/Title/Title.m4b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your given file name structure, with `sh`, `mkdir` and `mv` something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

for file in ./*.m4b; do
  author="${file%% *}"
  file_name="${file##* }"
  title="${file_name%.*}"
  echo mkdir -p "$author/$title" &&
  echo mv -v "$file" "$author/$title/$file_name"
done
```

---

Output:

```
mkdir -p ./Author/Title
mv -v ./Author - Title.m4b ./Author/Title/Title.m4b
```

---

Without all the `echo` , the output is like this on my side:

```
renamed './Author - Title.m4b' -> './Author/Title/Title.m4b'
```

---

This should handle your file names with spaces.

```
#!/bin/sh

for file in ./*.m4b; do
  author=${file%% -*}
  file_name=${file##*- }
  title=${file_name%.*}
  echo mkdir -p "$author/$title" &&
  echo mv -v "$file" "$author/$title/$file_name"
done
```

---

with `bashv4+` with the `=~` operator.

```
#!/bin/bash

regexp='^(.+) - (.*)\.(.+)$'
for file in ./*.m4b; do
  [[ $file =~ $regexp ]] &&
  author=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
  title=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
  file_name=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}.${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
  echo mkdir -p "$author/$title" &&
  echo mv -v "$file" "$author/$title/$file_name"
done
```

Output:

```
mkdir -p ./Author/Title
mv -v ./Author - Title.m4b ./Author/Title/Title.m4b
mkdir -p ./Dan Brown/Diabolus
mv -v ./Dan Brown - Diabolus.m4b ./Dan Brown/Diabolus/Diabolus.m4b
mkdir -p ./JRR Tolkien/Lord of the Rings
mv -v ./JRR Tolkien - Lord of the Rings.m4b ./JRR Tolkien/Lord of the Rings/Lord of the Rings.m4b
```

---

Without the `echo`

```
renamed './Author - Title.m4b' -> './Author/Title/Title.m4b'
renamed './Dan Brown - Diabolus.m4b' -> './Dan Brown/Diabolus/Diabolus.m4b'
renamed './JRR Tolkien - Lord of the Rings.m4b' -> './JRR Tolkien/Lord of the Rings/Lord of the Rings.m4b'
```

- Remove all the `echo` if you're satisfied with the output.

---

Output from the `tree` utility:

```
Author/
└── Title
    └── Title.m4b
Dan Brown/
└── Diabolus
    └── Diabolus.m4b
JRR Tolkien/
└── Lord of the Rings
    └── Lord of the Rings.m4b

3 directories, 3 files
```

---

- The script above works if you're inside the same directory as the files in question (relative path), otherwise change `./*.m4b` to its absolute path.
- See POSIX sh [Parameter Expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02)
- See [Bash Shell Paraemeter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

Comment: thanks so much! Being new to this, I assume I need to put this in a .sh file and then run it inside the folder with all the m4b files?

Comment: That somehow did not work. Out of "Dan Brown - Diabolus.m4b", the script makes "Dan\Diabolus\Diabolus.m4b". I also made a mistake in the initial post. The filename should remain untouched.

Comment: Right, because there are more spaces in the file names.

Comment: That was it thanks - I modified it a little, so that the filename has author and title in there. Appreciate your help!

Comment: One more question. In its current form the script executes the "cuts" for each " - ", how would I need to adjust it to only do it once on the first " - "?

Comment: @thimplicity, I believe this code `file_name=${file##*- }` does the second trimming.

Comment: At any rate, please read up on [PARAMETER EXPANSION](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073)  and look up `BASH_REMATCH` from the bash manual.